# I am getting this error when trying to load data on a website from an SQL server

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

Error: Error in query: Table 'jeanpaulcaruana1bsc5m.tbl_' doesn't exist

PHP

```
require_once("connection.php");

$connection = connectToMySQL();
$query = "select * from tbl_ members";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
    or die("Error in query: ".mysqli_error($connection));
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] =   $row;
}
```

Javascript

```
app.controller('getMembersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('php/showMembers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.members = data;
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(err){
        $log.error(err);
    });
});
```

Database name: `jeanpaulcaruana1bsc5m`

Table trying to access `tbl_members`

Comment: `tbl_ members` see a space?

Comment: `select * from tbl_ members` translates to: *select everything from tbl_ **< OOPS, I fell in a rabbit hole**, members*. You need to *"patch"* that hole ;-)

Comment: @u_mulder *Ah,* if only the guys down there were to have been able to cash in on that one eh? ;-) edit: ah, 1 so far. Still off-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space between "tbl_" and "members" in SQL query

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your query (a blank space in the name of the table).

`$query = "select * from tbl_members";`